How do I remove ".0" from the phone number STRING in SQL?
So I have a Phone number (PN) column in an SQL table as a TEXT. It is a text format because I do not want the POWER BI (Which will pull data from SQL with the Direct Query Setting) to read the PN as a number. The SQL table came from multiple CSV Files. Now some of the Phone numbers were stored as floats in the CSV files and when I converted them to Text in the SQL table, the decimal ".0" remained. Now it's a bit messy. I just want to know how to Alter the text of a specific column in the SQL table so I can replace the ".0" with "" or basically nothing.

Please add sample data for the table, or at least sample data for the phone number column where you require the replacement.

If it's always .0 that you want te remove you could use SQL REPLACE() function .

If you want to permanently replace it: update mytable set pn = replace(pn, '.0', ''). If you want to do it when selecting: select replace(pn, '.0', '') as pn ... from mytable or create a view this does this.

use regex_replace or string replace function to trim them.
sample query:
set @st = '102.0';
select @st, REGEXP_REPLACE(@st, '\\.\\d*', '') as IntVal;

set @st = '102.123123';
select @st, REGEXP_REPLACE(@st, '\\.\\d*', '') as IntVal;

set @st = '.98797234';
select @st, REGEXP_REPLACE(@st, '\\.\\d*', '') as IntVal;

set @st = '12313';
select @st, REGEXP_REPLACE(@st, '\\.\\d*', '') as IntVal;


sample code:
https://dbfiddle.uk/ARi3x5eQ

You need to escape . in the regexp, otherwise it matches any character.

Try it with set @st = '102.0' and you'll see the problem.

Sorry, @Barmar . I'm extremally sorry for my previous answer. I have update the answer with 'regex-replace', to remove all number after the decimal point including it. Handle all possible condition.
Please check latest one.
